# How to grow hight of parent div (with specified hight) to contain child

Tags: html, css

I have a homepage 'hero image' div with `height:100vh` and `max-height:800px`. Inside this div is a `h1`. It all works fine but when the screen is less high than the heading, the hero image div doesn't grow in hight to contain the heading. The child element - the heading - sticks out under the parent element. See screen grab:

[image]

Note: I want the max-height so that on larger screens the content below the hero image is visable without scrolling down.

I've tried setting a min-height with the max-height but as expected the min-hight overrides the max-height.

I've also tried different values for overflow but this doesn't effect the parent element.

So... how do I create a `div with height:100vh` and a `max-height` that will always be as high as its child contents?

I kind of need min-height and max-height to work together (but the min-height overrides the max-height)

```
<div class="hero_image">
    <h1>Heading line one<br>heading line two<br>heading line three</h1>
</div>  

.hero_image {
    height:100vh;
    max-height:600px;
    background-colour:blue;
}

.hero_image h1 {
    color:white;
    font-size:100px;
    padding-top:8vh;
}
```

See JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/d6b3rj8o/

==============

ONLY SOLUTION?

Is the only way to do this to use break points? See https://jsfiddle.net/z7fy8vhb/2/

```
.hero_image {
    min-height:100vh;
    }

@media screen and (min-height:600px) {

.hero_image {
    min-height:600px;
    }
}
```

Comment: you should remove max-height

Comment: I want the max-height so that on larger screens the content below the hero image is visable without scrolling down

Comment: Removing the max-height doesn't grow the div to fit its child

Comment: add background size:cover for hero image

Comment: I'm not using a background image so this won't work

Comment: if you use background image means posible to you asked

Comment: It's not that your hero image doesn't grow in height to accommodate the header -- it's that the default overflow behavior is such that elements are allowed to overflow their containers. Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: @amn yes I understand, but I'm not sure Ranjith does

Answer (score 1):

try like this

HTML

```
<div class="hero_image">
    <h1>Heading line one<br>heading line two<br>heading line three</h1>
</div>
```

css

```
*{
  margin:0;
}
.hero_image {
    height:100vh;
    max-height:600px;
    background-image:url(https://image.freepik.com/free-psd/abstract-background-design_1297-73.jpg);
    background-size:cover;
    }

.hero_image h1 {
    color:white;
    font-size:100px;
    margin:0;
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't work. See https://jsfiddle.net/d6b3rj8o/    make the 'results' panel very short and you can see that the heading isn't contained by the hero image – it sticks out

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

.hero_image {
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url(https://image.freepik.com/free-psd/abstract-background-design_1297-73.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}

.hero_image h1 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 100px;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero_image">
  <h1>Heading line one<br>heading line two<br>heading line three</h1>
</div>
```

Note:- 
remove `max-height:600px` and change  `height:100vh;` to  `height:100%`;

Comment: I want the max-height so that on larger screens the content below the hero image is visable without scrolling down